# Elegant way to use unix find for many file extensions and names

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I'm trying to use the `find` command to search for a long list of different file extensions and filenames, like `*.pl`, `*.sh`, `*.jar`, `FileA`, `FileB`...

My find command looks like:

```
find $dir -name '*.pl' -o -name '*.sh' -o -name ...
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this without spamming `-o -name`?  I would ultimately like to have an array of such filenames and extensions, and have `find` look for each one, since this would be more maintainable and readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it more succinctly with `-regex`, e.g. for your example:

```
find -E $dir -regex '.*\.(pl|sh|jar)' -o -regex '.*/File(A|B)'
```

Note that Linux find lacks the `-E` switch - you will have to use `-regextype posix-extended` in place of `-E` if you're using Linux (thanks to @Ansgar for pointing this out).

Comment: Cool!  What about the actual filenames; do I need a separate regex for those?

Comment: It depends whether they are all distinct file names or whether they have some part of the name in common. I've extended the answer above to include your example file names.

Comment: Some of the filenames have things in common (they start with FG), but several are distinct

Comment: Note that this will work only on systems with BSD `find`. GNU `find` doesn't support the option `-E`. You'll have to use `-regextype posix-extended -regex '...'` there.

Comment: @Ansgar: thanks for the clarification - I'm mainly a BSD person and didn't know that Linux find lacked this. I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: This is pretty elegant for file extensions, and similar filenames.  Would it be possible to store the distinct filenames in an array, and read from that for the find command?

Comment: You could probably write a simple bash script to do that.